# What is wrong with my Mongoose Relationship?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, relationship

I am learning mongoose relationship and stuck in this problem... someone tell me where am I wrong..? and Is there a better approach of doing this..?

**Employee.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { departmentSchema, addDepartment } = require("./Departments");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema();

const employeeModel = mongoose.model("Employee", {
  Name: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50 },
  Department: departmentSchema
});

async function addEmployee(Employee, Department, Language, Framework) {
  const result = await new employeeModel({
    ...Employee,
    Department: addDepartment(Department, Language, Framework)
  });
  return await result.save();
}
```

**Department.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { languageSchema, addLanguage } = require("./Language");

const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Depart: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50 },
  Languages: languageSchema
});

const DepartmentModel = mongoose.model("Department", departmentSchema);

async function addDepartment(Department, Language, Framework) {
  const result = await new DepartmentModel({
    ...Department,
    Languages: addLanguage(Language, Framework)
  });
  return await result.save();
}

module.exports = {
  departmentSchema,
  addDepartment
};
```

**Language.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { frameworkSchema, addFramework } = require("./Frameworks");

const languageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Language: { type: String, required: true },
  Framework: [frameworkSchema]
});

const languageModel = mongoose.model("Language", languageSchema);

async function addLanguage(Language, Framework) {
  const result = await new languageModel({
    ...Language,
    Framework: addFramework(Framework)
  });
  return await result.save();
}

module.exports = {
  languageSchema: languageSchema,
  addLanguage
};
```

**Framework.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const frameworkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Name: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 50 },
  Version: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 1, maxlength: 50 }
});

const frameworkModel = mongoose.model("Framework", frameworkSchema);

async function addFramework(Framework) {
  const result = await new frameworkModel(...Framework);
  return await result.save();
}

module.exports = {
  frameworkSchema,
  addFramework
};
```

**Error from Framework.js**

```
Found non-callable @@iterator
```

what I am trying to do is

1. Employee ->
2. Name
3. Department ->
4. Depart
5. Language ->
6. Language Name
7. Framework ->
8. Framework Name
9. Framework Version

Every -> represents a new object (collection)

I know it's a little bit complex for a newbie like me...
I am a MySql database user and I loved it but now I am trying to grasp NoSql...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the error as always :p

The error is because of the spread operator (...) in Framework.js

```
const result = await new frameworkModel(...Framework);
```

still if someone can tell me a better approach of doing this, it will be highly appreciated.

[image: This is what I was trying to achieve]

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you an example:
Suppose you have **employSchema** already like that:

```
const {Schema} = mongoose;
const employeeModel = mongoose.model("Employee", new Schema({
  Name: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50 },
  Department: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Department"}
}));
```

In the above model, I use **ref** property to connect to **Department** model through **ObjectId** (it mean "_id" property in Department collection).

Ex: You will create an new employeeModel like that:

```
let newEmployee = new employeeModel("Employee Name", Department ID here).
```

You absolutely do the opposite or do for others.
And you need to use **.populate()** function to query database.
Example:

```
employModel.find({}).populate("Department").exec(callback what you want to do);
```

You can read official document at: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thanks Hai Huynh Ngoc for replying... I am familiar with the method you discussed above (Normalization)... I was trying to embed documents (DeNormalization)